# How to see progress of restore dump after execute it

Tags: mysql, windows

I am trying to see the progress of the command

```
mysql -u root -p insight < E:\Mbit\Projects\insight.sql
```

after press enter, Is there any way to see the progress, in windows 10?

I have founded some files called ib_logfile, but it is unreadable